# Mydbr migration from one database host to other

Tags: php, reporting, mysql

I am trying to migrate MYdbr reporting tool from one DB host to other .

I did changes in the conf file and completed the set up . Took the db dump of mydbr

But i want to know where are stored procs stored ? I dont see the Report code anywhere .

Thanks in advance  :)

Comment: Did you use the `--routines` flag when you did `mysqldump`?

Comment: no i didnt . Will do that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--routines` flag of `mysqldump`.